# import data from web using Jexcel in android

Tags: android

I want to import data from excel to my application in android
I succeeded doing it local in my environment:

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shidur);
workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(in);
Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(0);
```

that's works fine if its in Raw folder.

But the problem is that *xls file is in web and i want to load it from http://...

Is it possible doing it?

thanks,

udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I figured it out finally.
It supports the follows:

URL u = new URL("http://www.domain.com/myexcelfile.xls");
InputStream in = u.openStream();